# Jquery .html() is removing space between words

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jQuery's `.html()` property to populate a select box. I have some options where I would like to preserve spaces between words, even if is more than one space. However, no matter how many spaces I leave in the `option` it seems to trim it to one space. Please view the attached snipped as an example, where I have 3 select options with multiple spaces but all resolves to a single space:

```js
$("#testSelect").html(`
                       <option>a b</option> 
                       <option>a  b</option>
                       <option>a                       b</option>
                       `);
                       
$("#testSelect").on("change", function(){
  console.log(`The value in the select box right now is ${$("#testSelect").val()}`)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testSelect">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.replaceAll` to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`:

```js
$("#testSelect").html(`
                       <option>a b</option> 
                       <option>a  b</option>
                       <option>a                       b</option>
                       `.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;"));

$("#testSelect").on("change", function() {
  console.log(`The value in the select box right now is ${$("#testSelect").val()}`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testSelect">
</select>
```